# C++ - Error with iteration of vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iteration

```
struct user
{
    vector<size_t> follower;
    vector<size_t> following;
};

int main ()
{
    vector< user > node ( 100 );

    // Pushing back some indices of other nodes in some node[x].follower and node[x].following

    size_t i = 2;

    for ( size_t const& j : node[i].follower )
        node[j].following.erase( remove( node[j].following.begin(), node[j].following.end(), i ), node[j].following.end() );

}
```

In C++, I created the `struct user`, where vectors `follower` and `following` store indices to some other users belonging to the `vector node`. With the last `for` loop I would like to destroy all the indices `i` (which refer to the specific `user i`) from the `vector follower` and `following` of other users; unluckily, with `gcc/4.7.2`, using C++11, I obtain this error:

```
error: cannot convert 'std::vector<long unsigned int>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long unsigned int*, std::vector<long unsigned int> >}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int remove(const char*)'
```

I also tried with a `for` loop of iterators, `for ( vector<size_t>::iterator it = node[i].follower.begin(); it != node[i].follower.end(); ++it )`, using `*it` in the code of the loop, but I still obtain a similar error.

I don't know what to do.

Comment: The code you posted [compiles fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48078131585571de). Did you include `algorithm`? Try dropping `using namespace std;` and qualify explicitly as `std::` - you might have some other `remove` visible.

Comment: I knew it was a stupid error...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Otherwise, compiler tries to use other `remove` function which is for deleting files and accepts a C-style strings (By including `<iostream>`).

Comment: Seriously? And for the last 2 mins I was like "why won't that worK" :D +1